# Transform div over a particular angle

Tags: html, css

I need a line and should have an option to change the angle. The transform property works well but when the angle is increased the line size is decreased.
I need to retain the line size and should not be affected.

https://jsfiddle.net/4j8n45zz/

```css
div {
  width: 5px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: yellow;
  /* Rotate div */
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: can you clarify ** the line size is decreased** .... ? an example?

Comment: it is overflowing the screen- line size stays the same...

Comment: @DaniP: https://jsfiddle.net/u91m80s2/2/ ...Here is an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `transform-origin` of the transformation is set on the middle of your `<div>`. So if you increase the angle the `<div>` will be rotate on the mid point and a part of your line is outside the site. To solve this you have to set the `transform-origin` to a corner (`[top, bottom] [right, left]`).

**See the following example (https://jsfiddle.net/4j8n45zz/1/):**

```css
div {
  display:block;
  width:5px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: yellow;
  /* Rotate div */
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```